# cpanel shell script on cloud server centos no such file or dir

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have a shell script copy_files.sh which I call once a day using a cron job.

However it has never worked I keep getting no such file or directory.

```
!#/bin/sh
for f in /home/site1/public_html/admin/data/*.csv
do 
  cp -v "$f" /home/site2/app/cron_jobs/data/"${f%.csv}".csv
done
```

I have checked via ssh that all paths are correct I have varified the path to /bin/sh using `ls -l /bin/sh` I have set perms and user and group to root for copy_files.sh I have disabled php open_basedir protection.

the shell script is in /home/site2/

Any ideas why I am still getting no such file or directory?
Is there anyway to check open_basedir protection is off that said considering the script is owned by root I don't see that being the problem unless it's executed as site2 user and not root?

Comment: The first line of your script is wrong, the shebang starts with '#!' not '!#'

Comment: opps typo ! you are correct I am getting cp: cannot stat and no such file or directory

Comment: Can you paste the exact output / error message (or portion of it) here please

Comment: cp: cannot stat ‘/home/site1/public_html/admin/data/*.csv’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way you use shell expansion, the variable in your for loop contains the absolute path to your files. Having the absolute path, means there is no need to use string manipulation (%) nor do you need to add the ".csv" to the filename, just get rid of it all together and provide the directory to which you're copying as your second argument to cp, see the example below.

`#!/bin/sh
for f in /home/site1/public_html/admin/data/*.csv; do
    cp -v "$f" /home/site2/app/cron_jobs/data
done`

Comment: still getting the same error ````cp: cannot stat ‘/home/site1/public_html/admin/data/*.csv’: No such file or directory```` I am only after copying 6 files I could explicitly name them but for future use it would be nice to pull all csv's from the dir

Comment: Are there any csv files in that directory? Can you provide the output of ls /home/site1/public_html/admin/data/*.csv

Comment: some of it there are loads: ````8mobile.csv                         Nokia-Lumia-620.csv
Apple-iPhone-4-8GB.csv              Nokia-Lumia-625.csv
````

Comment: One last thing, try running your script manually, using "sh -x yourScript.sh" and let me know what the output is

Comment: it works when run manually ````+ for f in '/home/site1/public_html/admin/data/*.csv'
+ cp -v /home/site1/public_html/admin/data/8mobile.csv /home/site2/app/cron_jobs/data
‘/home/site1/public_html/admin/data/8mobile.csv’ -> ‘/home/site2/app/cron_jobs/data/8mobile.csv’````

Comment: In case this helps anyone else the issue was I set the cron job up in cpanel under the user of site2 even though I have disabled php open_basedir protection the cron still did not have permission to go outside its own home dir, so I set the cron up manually in the terminal using ````crontab-e```` now it works without issue